# JavaFX parameterized editable tableview

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to add an editable table to my project, and [I found this code](http://www.wobblycogs.co.uk/index.php/computing/javafx/100-javafx-2-generic-editable-table-cells) that gives an outline to what I'm trying to do. However, it is not parameterized, which is what seems to make it work (My code keeps giving me type errors). Is there a way to parameterize this or are raw types ok in this situation?

Comment: Is your table all strings?  Do you need or want custom editing cells?  [TextFieldTableCell](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html#forTableColumn--) is a simpler solution.

Comment: I'd like to use integers and doubles, I'd have to do a bit of checking to just use strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always better to parameterize the `TableView` and the `TableColumn`s.

The code you linked is somewhat "legacy" as it uses raw types and doesn't utilize the helper cell classes, such as `TextFieldTableCell`.

`TextFieldTableCell` provides a static [`forTableColumn(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html#forTableColumn-javafx.util.StringConverter-) method that takes a `StringConverter<T>` and returns a `Callback` which can be used as a `cellFactory` for a `TableColumn<S,T>`. The `StringConverter<T>` just provides methods for converting a `String` entered into the `TextField` into a `T`, and for converting a `T` into a `String` to be displayed in the cell.

There are standard `StringConverter`s provided for numeric types, such as `IntegerStringConverter` and `DoubleStringConverter`.

Try something along the lines of:

```
TableView<MyDataType> table = new TableView<>();

TableColumn<MyDataType, Integer> intColumn = new TableColumn<>("Int Column");
intColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));

TableColumn<MyDataType, Double> doubleColumn = new TableColumn<>("Double Column");
doubleColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));
```