# how to edit a table cell that has a number?

Tags: javafx, edit, editing

im coding javaFX
how on earth do you guys edit a table cell that has a number for a value.
in the code below im only getting an error in the first line alone, 
incompatibility and cannot be converted  types of errors

here is the vital part of the code, please can some one help me by fixing this bit of code.

thanks in advance

```
 ppriceCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Product, Number>forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));
   ppriceCol.setOnEditCommit(
             (CellEditEvent<Product, Double> t) -> {
             ((Product) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
             .setPprice(t.getNewValue());
          });
```

the few examples that are on the net seems to be old legacy dated codes even oracle themselves shows examples only for editable String cells. after 2 days looking i did find another person in my boat here on this site but the solution was provided from another user who stated that his java was a bit rusty hence the solution didn't work

Comment: try:  `ppriceCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));`

Comment: @ Win.ubuntu 
you Sir is a genius.... wow, for two days im here going bald trying to find the solution. i really appreciate and thank you so much.

this is my first post meaning i dont know as yet a few things about this is site... how do i rate your answer, give a badge or acts to those intention?

thank you again

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX parameterized editable tableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581705/javafx-parameterized-editable-tableview)